# Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[editor]?' is not a valid attribute name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ckeditor

**The error occurred as a result of this sequence:**

1. Go to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/angular.html.
2. Try to execute the CKEditor in your Angular program and get error like in this [github issue](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/12222).
3. Try to make some temporary solution: *remove the null check for the CKEditor_Version field and make the type string.*
4. Type the command `ng serve` and see it in the browser (Chrome).
5. Click on the right side of the mouse and follow the **inspect** to open dev tools.
6. Go to the "Console" tab menu and see the error such as:

[image]

#### ❌ Actual result

*It's impossible to utilize **`<ckeditor [editor]?="Editor"></ckeditor>`** tag in HTML file.*

- Installed CKEditor plugins: FROM `'@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'`

Comment: `[editor]?=` is not a valid HML attribute for angular, change it to `[editor]=`

Comment: @NarenMurali, no different. It still shows errors.

Comment: please share stackblitz to validate!

Comment: @NarenMurali, please look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jpjmge?file=src/app/app.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have incorrectly imported the `ClassicEditor` Please modify the below line!

Before:

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
```

After:

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
```

.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  Editor = ClassicEditor;
  title = 'CKEditorAngularApp';
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-whx273)

[stackblitz example 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-ckeditor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you, bro. If it is done as you say, it will work. ✅

Answer (score 0):

import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OFd5.png)

Test answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).